# Does changing Username in Active Directory impact Login into SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, active-directory

I have a requirement to change a username in Active Directory from *domain\testuser1* to *domain\testuser2* But my concern is whether the new changes will be synced automatically  with SharePoint so that I can login with new username i.e. *domain\testuser2* without any problem?

If not auto sync then How can SharePoint profiles be synced with Active Directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint will not recognize the changed sAMAccountName until the following is executed:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "domain\testuser1" -Web https://siteCollectionUrl 
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "domain\testuser2" -IgnoreSid
```

Comment: Hi @MSallal Thanks for post.
For Login part I am clear but want to check Is there any Powershell or stsadm command to sync it? 
I found this link as well addressing the same https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/user-login-name-changed-in-ad-how-to-sync-with-sharepoint.html

Comment: yes use $user = Get-SPUser -Identity "oldusername" -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "newUerName" -IgnoreSid

Comment: Fine Thanks for the update